# How do I use pandoc --filter pandoc-citeproc with biblatex' filtering capacity?

Tags: biblatex, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I would like to use `pandoc` to produce a Word document filtering some bibliographic entries.

The following LaTeX code produced in TeXShop filters properly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}

@article{doc1,
  title = {Title1},
  author = {author},
  date = {2018-04-29},
  keywords = {article}
}

@book{doc2,
  title = {Title1},
  author = {author},
  date = {2018-04-29},
  keywords = {book}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword={book}]

\end{document}
```

But when I save that as, say `sample.tex` and run: 
`pandoc sample.tex -o sample.docx --filter pandoc-citeproc`

It does not filter the bibliographic entries. Thank you!

Comment: You can use only `pandoc-citeproc` when converting to .docx, that means that you can't use `biblatex`

Comment: I was using that. Does it not filter the bibliographies? Is there a workaround, or am I stuck making a pdf and then converting the pdf to word?

Comment: `biblatex` only works with LaTeX, so filtering doesn't work when converting to `.docx`

Comment: Maybe you can use a pandoc filter, like: https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/blob/master/multiple-bibliographies/README.md

Comment: You could try [`make4ht`](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht): `make4ht -f odt filename.tex` to get an `.odt` document, then on with libre office to `.docx`.